# How to load a Database associated with a Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio. Logged into the proper server.  I'm loading a previously used Query. I have selected (in Object Explorer) the Database it was associated with.

But I get an error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'dbo.model'.
```

If I create a *new* Query, it works fine.
I think the issue is that the Database isn't "loaded". (I'm new to SQL Management Studio).

Comment: Opening the database in Object Explorer does not set the database context for the query  window. Either execute a `USE` command in the query window to set the database context or select the database from the drop down list on the query editor toolbar.

Comment: @DanGuzman this comment looks suspiciously like an answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the Database for the Query in either of these ways:

1. Include a `USE` statement to specify the database context
2. Choose the relevant database in the *Available Databases* drop down in the Query toolbar.

[image: SQL Server Management Studio]